# How to use FsXaml's CommandDependecy/(ies)

Tags: wpf, f#, fsxaml, fsharp.viewmodule

Here is what I have done using FsXaml

```
type MainViewModel() as self = 
inherit ViewModelBase() 

    let listOfData = self.Factory.Backing(<@self.ListOfData@>, 0 :> obj)
    let selectedId = self.Factory.Backing(<@self.SelectedId@>, 0)

    member x.SelectedId with get() = selectedId.Value 
                        and set value = selectedId.Value <- value;
                                        x.ListOfData <- returnPrice(value) :> obj        
    member x.StockList with get() = stockList
    member x.ListOfData with get() = listOfData.Value and set value = listOfData.Value <- value
```

and in xaml

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding StockList}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Code" 
              SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}"/>
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfData}"/>
```

How can I use command dependecy of `ViewModule` to set `x.ListOfData` instead of calling `returnPrice(value)` in setter of `x.SelectedId`?

Comment: I assume you want to use `self.DependencyTracker.AddPropertyDependencies`.

Comment: Please write [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You assumed it right @Foggy Finder. I have replaced the code to -

```
let selectedId = self.Factory.Backing(<@self.SelectedId@>, 0)  

do
    self.DependencyTracker.AddPropertyDependency(<@self.ListOfData@>,<@self.SelectedId@>)

member x.SelectedId with get() = selectedId.Value and set value = selectedId.Value <- value;
member x.StockList with get() = stockList
member x.ListOfData with get() = returnPrice(self.SelectedId)
```

and it works!

What is the purpose of self.DependencyTracker.AddCommandDependency() and How to use it?

Comment: never used this function. But the purpose is clear from the name.

Comment: That kind of belongs in a separate question - but in general, it's something you don't (normally) need to use yourself.  It works like the property depednencies, but for teh canexecute of a command.  Normally, when you create the command, you just include it in the dependent expressions, and the framework wires that up for you.

Comment: Thanks @ReedCopsey for your comment. Can you please suggest me some site/blog/video link as starter's guide to get idea about developing ASP.NET MVC application using F#?

Comment: @emonhaque I'd recommend joining the F# software foundation, and asking in the Web channel of their slack team... likely will get the best answer.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Thanks once again. FsMvc5 is the right one for me.